# Finding subtree in a tree

Tags: graph, trees

I have a tree:

```
    a
   / \
  b   c
 / \
d   f
   / \ 
  g   h
```

And the pattern:

```
    x
   / \
  y   z
 / \
q   p
```

As output I would like to have:

```
x: a
y: b
z: c
q: d
p: f
```

and

```
x: b
y: f
z: c
q: g
p: h
```

Is there any algorithm I could look at?

Comment: your first pattern could be done with an easy breadth-first traversal (and stop after *n* nodes, where n = 5). The second pattern is a little weird to me because you process node *f* before *c* and *g* and *h*.

Comment: @Frustrated, the second example makes sense if you assume that the order of children doesn't matter, which is a valid assumption for some trees.

Comment: @KarlBielefeldt: I suppose... what threw me off is that *c* is a *sibling* of *b* but it is processed after *b* 's child is procesed, and before *b* 's grandchildren.

Comment: I see what you mean.  I thought he said `d` instead of `c`.

Comment: I'm pretty sure he *meant* d instead of c.

Comment: I ment `d` instead of `c`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Flatten your pattern into a breadth-first array of tuples including the *node name*, *depth*, and *index*, like:

> (a,0,0), (b,1,0), (c,1,1), (d,2,0)...
>
> Traverse (or flatten) your input tree in breadth-first order, ideally using the same method.
>
> The n-th item in your pattern array will match the n-th item in the input tree, assuming there is one. You can use the depth and index values of each tuple to skip ahead until something matches.
>
> There are really good breadth-first traversal code samples all over the place, it should be easy to find one in the language of your choice.